# .NET 7 Environment variables in appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, environment-variables, .net-7.0

In Java, I use a file called `application.properties` where I can reference environment variables like this

```
database.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

In **.NET 7** we use `appsettings.json` to define configurations for our application.

In my specific case, Azure is going to have all these configurations values stored in a Keyvault that is going to be used as environment variables to my .NET 7 application. I don't know any value that is stored in keyvault so having one appsettings file for each environment with everything in it is not an option.

What I need to have is something similar to what happens in Java, I imagined something like:

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "DatabaseUrl":"${DATABASE_URL}"
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Or maybe another way to replace this config value with the environment variable.

Comment: If you want to refer to a configuration value that's stored in an environment variable, why don't you just use the environment variables directly? ASP.NET Core, for example, can use environment variables to directly initialize configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#non-prefixed-environment-variables. You can also get secrets from Azure Key Vault directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: When you deploy your app, your configurations will get automatically overriden by things like env variables and Azure keyvault whenever possible. You can read more about configuration here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0. You'll want to pay attention to the hierarchical keys formatting for keyvault in that article.

Comment: We are achieving this by CI/CD pipelines. the appsettings.json file's placeholders get replaced during deployment process

Answer (score 0):

```
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = builder.Configuration
 .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
 .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: false)
 .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true)
 .AddEnvironmentVariables()
 .Build();

var databaseUrl = configuration.GetSection("DatabaseUrl");
```

You simply add more EnvVars in the launchSettings, eg AN_ENVVAR_ENDPOINT:

```
 "profiles": {
    "MyApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7034;http://localhost:5034",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "AN_ENVVAR_ENDPOINT": "https://localhost:7052/v4.0/Version"
      }
    },
```

Comment: did you even read the question?

Answer (score 0):

I use like this in C#

{
"DatabaseUrl":"$env:DATABASE_URL"
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The correct env Keywords is `%envName%`.

If you has env:`$env:my_env1`.

You should use `%my_env1%`.

But,You can not use `%%` direct in `appsettings.json`.

Base on [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

You can add `%my_env1%` in `launchSettings.json`.

So,your `launchSettings.json` file just like:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "YourProjactName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DatabaseUrl": "%DATABASE_URL%"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:12262/"
    }
}
```

It works only in **debug model**.

If you want work with deploment .

You can see

```
"environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DatabaseUrl": "%DATABASE_URL%"
      }
```

It means send `DatabaseUrl` and `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to application.It will auto apply to the same key in `appsettings.json`
So,Just name **environment name** as **json key name** will worked.

So,You can add `DatabaseUrl` environment param.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to provide [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0). But rather than the java convention, where environment variables are mapped explicitly. The typical pattern is to just import all environment variables with a specific prefix.

```cs
IHostBuilder host;
host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) => {
    builder
        .SetBasePath(ctx.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{ctx.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables("MYPREFIX_");
    var vaultName = ctx.Configuration["AZUREKEYVAULT"];
    if (vaultName != null)
        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
            new Uri($"https://{vaultName}.vault.azure.net/"),
            new DefaultAzureCredential(
                new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions{
                    // exclude any credentials you need to avoid using
                })
        );
})
```

Then you may configure the environment variable `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` to provide optional configuration from source control or build artifacts. `MYPREFIX_` for any other non-secret configuration. And `DOTNET_AZUREKEYVAULT` to provide external secrets.

Note that `DefaultAzureCredential` will look at environment variables to provide credentials to access the key vault. For example when running in an azure VM, you may need to set `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` to identify a user managed identity.